# Incorrect result when finding max and min of user input

Tags: python

my code is as follows:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break

    try:
        ival = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None: 
        largest = num
        continue
    elif num < largest:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None: 
        smallest = num
        continue
    elif num > smallest:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

I need help because the proper min and max is not being displayed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I hope you get only one input and could you tell me what logic you follow to find large or small? Example: If I put input 10, What is your expected output?

Comment: You don't use variable `ival`, but compare strings instead

Comment: i get one input at a time until i enter done( inputs are 7, 2, jane, 10, and 4). my max shows 10 like i want it to but my min shows 4 which is incorrect.

Comment: Also comparison logic for max and min seem to be swapped

Comment: i was told to use ival

Comment: yeah i had them the other way around <, >, but then my min was showing 10.

Comment: Why are you converting `ival = int(num)` to integer, if you never actually **use** that variable?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct. You forgot that you are dealing with `ival = int(num)` since your `num` is actually a *string* until you converted it explicitly to integer type, because input() call always returns string. And you slightly messed `<` and `>`, so double check these statements.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break

    try:
        ival = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest is None: 
        largest = ival
        continue
    elif largest < ival:     
        largest = ival

    if smallest is None: 
        smallest = ival
        continue
    elif ival < smallest:
        smallest = ival

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: it says not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' for line: elif ival > largest :

Comment: oh missed something. thank you soooooo much!!

Comment: @Julie Did you remember to change all assignments from `num` to `ival`? `largest = num` -> `largest = ival` and so on

Comment: Also those `if..elif`s can be changed to: `if largest is None or largest < ival`  and `if smallest is None or ival < smallest` since the `if` and `elif` blocks both do the same thing